# Reverse coding in matlab

Tags: matlab, recode

I have a survey data in matlab and I have some reverse coded items. All I need is to do reverse coding in certain questions.I was using this code  `reversecoding = myStruct.mysurvey(:,4) == 5 ;
       mySturct.mysurvey(reversecoding,4) = 3 ;` but I realized I will probably have some issues by using this.

For example when I recode the value of 3 to 5;

```
 myStruct.mysurvey=
  3     3     3     3
  6     6     6     6
  3     3     3     3
  7     6     6     7
  4     3     5     5 <--
  5     5     4     5 <--
       ...

reversecoding = myStruct.mysurvey(:,4) == 5 ;
   mySturct.mysurvey(reversecoding,4) = 3 

%after (the last 2 values has recoded to 3)


 myStruct.mysurvey=
  3     3     3     3
  6     6     6     6
  3     3     3     3
  7     6     6     7
  4     3     5     3 <--
  5     5     4     3 <--
       ...
```

But after that, when I am recoding the 3 to 5 it recodes my all 3s (including the ones that I just recoded from 5) to 5.

To exemplify;

```
    %after I recode 3s to 5

 myStruct.mysurvey=
  3     3     3     3
  6     6     6     6
  3     3     3     3
  7     6     6     7
  4     3     5     3 <--
  5     5     4     3 <--
       ...

     reversecoding = myStruct.mysurvey(:,4) == 3 ;
   mySturct.mysurvey(reversecoding,4) = 5 ;
```

myStruct.mysurvey=
      3     3     3     5
      6     6     6     6
      3     3     3     5
      7     6     6     7
      4     3     5     5 <--
      5     5     4     5 <--     %they are 5 again 
           ...
     %again the last two values of column 4 goes back to 5...

How can I get rid of this problem? This is the code;

```
reversecoding = myStruct.mysurvey(:,4) == 5 ;
   mySturct.mysurvey(reversecoding,4) = 3 ;
% after
 reversecoding = myStruct.mysurvey(:,4) == 3 ;
   mySturct.mysurvey(reversecoding,4) = 5 ;
 % all other values will be transformed.
 %old 1 will be 7
 %old 2 will be 6
      ...
 %old 6 will be 2
 %old 7 will be 1
```

What is the best way to recode them? I will be recoding from 1 to 7.

Comment: Create some copy of the original, then reference from that static copy to change the data instead of referencing the live, changing version. This way you wont have the 3 to 5 / 5 to 3 situation you describe.

Comment: Didn't I see this exact same question yesterday? It had exactly the same typo too. If you are going to delete a question and repost it, at least correct the typos that were pointed out. Equality and assignment are different operators. The 2nd and 4th `==` should be `=`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's not the exact same question. I changed it (edited 2 hours ago)  also I was not aware of that typo because I am not a expert at Matlab, that's why I am asking. If you scroll down you can see that I corrected my typos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [container map](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) to create the mapping from old to new values. This is quite simple:

```
map = containers.Map(old_values, new_values);
```

or in your case

```
map = containers.Map(1:10, 10:-1:1);
```

you can then use `map` to map an old value to its corresponding new value like this:

```
>> map(1)
ans =
    10
>> map(4)
ans =
     7
```

Note that you can only "call" `map` on single values, and not on arrays. But you can use e.g. `arrayfun` to simplify this to one call:

```
>> myStruct.mysurvey(:, 4) = [9, 2, 1, 10, 4];    % Example data
>> myStruct.mysurvey(:, 4)
ans =
     9
     2
     1
    10
     4

>> myStruct.mysurvey(:, 4) = arrayfun(@(x) map(x), myStruct.mysurvey(:, 4));
>> myStruct.mysurvey(:, 4)
ans =
     2
     9
    10
     1
     7
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this problem but it is kind of a pain in the neck.

I created different variables for each value by using logical indexing.

```
%find elements to recode

fiveto3 = myStruct.mySurvey(:,4) == 5 ;
threeto5 = myStruct.mySurvey(:,4) == 3 ;
...
twoto6= myStruct.mySurvey(:,4)== 2;
sixto2= myStruct.mySurvey(:,4)== 6;
 ...
oneto7= myStruct.mySurvey(:,4) == 1;
sevento1 = myStruct.mySurvey(:,4)==7;
% time to recode
 myStruct.mySurvey(fiveto3 , 4) = 3 ;
 myStruct.mySurvey(threeto5,4) = 5 ;
 myStruct.mySurvey(twoto6 , 4) = 6 ;
 myStruct.mySurvey(sixto2 , 4) = 2 ;
 myStruct.mySurvey(oneto7 , 4) = 7 ;
 myStruct.mySurvey(sevento1 , 4) = 1 ;

 clear fiveto3 threeto5 twoto6 sixto2 oneto7 sevento1 % to get rid of these variables.
```

This works too but it needs more effort and more lines if you have more than 10 values to recode. You can both try container map or this one!